# Kendo Chart With JSRender+Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, jsrender, jsviews

I have a grid in which one of the columns I am drawing a trendline using Kendo Chart. 
The issue is that the chart only shows up in one of the rows and when I refresh the page it changes the position on which row the graph shows .Sometimes it doesn't show up at all .(Screenshots attached)
I have tried passing unique divId's,Unique chart names to the javascript function with no luck.  {{:~trend('Mydiv',#parent.parent.data)}}
The only thing that I see missing is a return statement from Javascript function to JsRender which I cannot return as its a kendoChart
Here is a  my JsRender Code and Javascript helper function .Also including screenshots of the trendline.

```
   script id="customGridTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
<div class="table-wrapper  dashboard-grid" id="main">
    {^{for data)}}
    {{!-- Get Column Headers --}}
    {{if #getIndex() == 0}}
    <div class="table-head">
        {{props}}
        {{for key}}
        <div class="table-col">
            <div class="table-th">{{:}}</div>
        </div>
        {{/for}}
        {{/props}}
    </div>
    {{/if}}
    {{/for}}
    {^{for data}}
    <div class="table-row">
        {{!-- Get Rows --}}
        {{props}}
        {{for}}

        <div class="table-col">
            <div class="table-th">{{if key=='' || key == null}} &nbsp;{{else}} {{>key}} {{/if}}</div>
            <div class="table-td">
                {{if #getIndex() == 0}}
                <img title="Summary" id="displaySummary" data-link="name{:prop}" src="/Images/InfoImgIcon.png" alt="" height="16" width="14" />
                {{if prop=='' || prop == null}} &nbsp; {{else}} {{:prop}} {{/if}}
                {{else  key=='Trend'}}
          <div id="Mydiv">{{:~trend('Mydiv',#parent.parent.data)}}</div>
                </div>
                {{else  key=='Status'}}
                {{if prop=='-1'}} <div><img title="" id="imgSquare" src="/Images/square.svg" alt="" height="16" width="14" /></div> {{/if}}
                {{if prop=='0'}} <div><img title="" id="imgTriangle" src="/Images/triangle.svg" alt="" height="16" width="14" /></div> {{/if}}
                {{if prop=='1'}} <div><img title="" id="imgCircle" src="/Images/circle.svg" alt="" height="16" width="14" /></div> {{/if}}
                {{else}}
                {{if prop=='' || prop == null}} &nbsp; {{else}} {{:prop}} {{/if}}{{/if}}
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        {{/for}}
        {{/props}}

    </div>
    {{/for}}       
        </div>    

            <div class="modal fade" data-link="id{:~WidgetId}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Metric Summary</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <table class=" table table-striped table-condensed">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="65%">
                                            <table width="100%">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="2">
                                                            <table>
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr><td>Metric Definition:&nbsp;</td><td> {{:Summary.MetricDefinition}}</td></tr>
                                                                    <tr><td>Metric Owner:&nbsp;</td><td>{{:Summary.MetricOwner}}</td></tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #E8E8E8"><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td width="32%">
                                                            <ul type="square" style="color:#5cb85c"><li><span style="color:#000000">Highlights:</span></li></ul>
                                                            {{for Summary}}
                                                            {{props CommentaryHighlights}}
                                                            {{>prop}}<br />
                                                            {{/props}}
                                                            {{/for}}
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td width="32%">
                                                            <ul type="square" style="color: #d9534f;"><li><span style="color:#000000">Lowlights:</span></li></ul>
                                                            {{for Summary}}
                                                            {{props CommentaryLowlights}}
                                                            {{>prop}}<br />
                                                            {{/props}}
                                                            {{/for}}
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="35%" height="100%">
                                            <div><table><tbody><tr><td>Graph Filter</td><td>
                                                                                            <select name="cars">
                                                                                                <option value="YoY">YoY</option>
                                                                                                <option value="MoM">MoM</option>                                                                                                    
                                                                                            </select>
                                                </td></tr></tbody></table></div>
                                            <div style="border: 1px solid #E8E8E8; height: 200px;">
                                                <div id="chart"></div>
                                            </div>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" id="btnClose" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

--------End JSRender Snippet-----------

----------Beging HelperFunction  trend------

```
    function BindTrendLineChart(TrendDivId, MetricTrendData) {
[![enter image description here][1]][1]   
var trendLineDataSource = TrendLineDataSource(MetricTrendData) 
$("#" + TrendDivId).kendoChart({
    dataSource: {
        data: trendLineDataSource,
        group: {
            field: "data"
        }
    },
    series: [{          
        type: "line",
        field: "value",
        style: "smooth",
        markers: {
            visible: false
        }
    }],
    categoryAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ""
        },
        majorGridLines: {
            visible: false
        },
        majorTicks: {
            visible: false
        }
    },
    valueAxis: {
        max: 3,
        title: {
            text: "voltage"
        },
        majorGridLines: {
            visible: false
        },
        visible: false
    },
    chartArea: {
        width: 100,
        height: 30
    },
    legend: {
        position: "custom",
        orientation: "horizontal",
        visible: false
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have not taken into account the processing model of JsViews. Your `{{:~trend('Mydiv',#parent.parent.data)}}` helper function is called during the rendering of the template (which is the first stage of the `link(...)` method). Only after that is the rendered output inserted into the DOM.

So if you had simply put a JavaScript break point in your code at: `$("#" + TrendDivId).kendoChart({...` you would see that `$("#" + TrendDivId)` returns `null` - since that `<div>` does not yet exist in the DOM.

The correct thing to do is to render the chart after data linking has happened. One neat way of doing that is to define a JsViews tag control for Kendo charts, and then do the rendering of the chart in the onAfterLink handler of the tag control.

```
// Define a kendochart tag
$.views.tags("kendochart", {
  onAfterLink: function(tagCtx, linkCtx) {
    // Bind to the data-linked element, and pass the data argument
    $(linkCtx.elem).kendoChart(tagCtx.args[0]); 
  }
});
```

You can then use it in your template like this:

```
<div data-link="{kendochart chartdata}"></div>
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/uvcrvepL/

Comment: Thank you Boris!  I integrated your code into my codebase but I still have the same problem with the chart rendering on the first row of the datagrid

Comment: But you are not even using the `{kendochart}` tag in your template! You need to replace the line `<div id="Content">{{:~trend(#parent.parent.parent....}}</div>` by `<div  data-link="{kendochart chartdata}"></div>` or similar - and define your app object with `chartdata` or similar, before you call `link(...)`. You don't need the `~trend(...)` helper at all...

Answer (score 0):

DrillDownGrid.Cshtml

```
<script id="customGridTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">

<div class="table-wrapper  dashboard-grid" id="main">
    {^{for data)}}
    {{!-- Get Column Headers --}}
    {{if #getIndex() == 0}}
    <div class="table-head">
        {{props}}
        {{for key}}
        <div class="table-col">
            <div class="table-th">{{:}}</div>
        </div>
        {{/for}}
        {{/props}}
    </div>
    {{/if}}
    {{/for}}
    {^{for data}}
    <div class="table-row">
        {{!-- Get Rows --}}
        {{props}}
        {{for}}
        <div class="table-col">
            <div class="table-th">{{if key=='' || key == null}} &nbsp;{{else}} {{>key}} {{/if}}</div>
            <div class="table-td">
                {{if #getIndex() == 0}}
                <img title="Summary" id="displaySummary" data-link="name{:prop}" src="/Images/InfoImgIcon.png" alt="" height="16" width="14" />
                {{if prop=='' || prop == null}} &nbsp; {{else}} {{:prop}} {{/if}}
                {{else  key=='Trend'}}
                <div>

                    <div id="Content">{{:~trend(#parent.parent.parent.parent.data.MetricId,#parent.parent.data)}}</div>
```

----------------------------------End Snippet------------------------------------

Drilldowngrid.js:

```
function BindTrendLineChart(TrendDivId, MetricTrendData) {
debugger;
var app = {
    chartdata: {
        title: "",
        seriesDefaults: {
            type: "line",
            style: "smooth"
        },
        series: [
          { name: "Example Series", data: [.20, .30, .40, .50, .60, .70, .70, .70, .70, 1] }
        ],
        categoryAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ""
            },
            majorGridLines: {
                visible: false
            },
            majorTicks: {
                visible: false
            }
        },
        valueAxis: {
            max: 3,
            title: {
                text: "voltage"
            },
            majorGridLines: {
                visible: false
            },
            visible: false
        },
        chartArea: {
            width: 100,
            height: 30
        },
        legend: {
            position: "custom",
            orientation: "horizontal",
            visible: false
        }
    }
};

$.views.tags("kendochart", { // Define a kendochart tag
    onAfterLink: function (tagCtx, linkCtx) {
        $(linkCtx.elem).kendoChart(tagCtx.args[0]); // Bind to the data-linked element
    }
});
$.link.theTmpl("#Content", app);
```

}